# Is there a WebDataRocks development roadmap?

Tags: webdatarocks

I am new to javascript, and I am looking for a pivot table js tool for my project. I can not find a roadmap for WebDataRocks, is there any? or is  the project being maintained ?cause I find the last updated date was one year ago.

Answer (score 0):

There is no roadmap for WebDataRocks, but each new release is accompanied by a blog post. Here is a link to the latest release: https://www.webdatarocks.com/blog/webdatarocks-1-3-1-pivot-with-django-jupyter-notebook-amcharts/.

As far as I know, the WebDataRocks team also provides another similar pivot table component which they are actively maintaining.